# How to merge a bunch of revisions defaulting all to overwrite local changes in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Scenario:
I have multiple release branches all being modified concurrently.
We then merge all changes from the lowest release branch to the highest release branch in order.

As each major (**1**.0) and minor (1.**1**) release are deployed to production, we merge the release to trunc.

I would like to be able to set the merge to happen w/out me having to click the `Prefer repository` button for each inevitable conflict.

Is there a setting to do this?
Or maybe a way to do this w/ just SVN?

**UPDATED:**
When I try to do the merge using `--accept theirs-full` I get an error.
It looks like It isn't handling tree conflicts.

Command:
`svn merge -r 20157:24006 https://.../branches/releases/Release_5_0 --accept theirs-full`

Error:

```
...
Resolved conflicted state of '...\FileX'
Resolved conflicted state of '...\FileY.java'
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 36 remaining (and 7 already resolved)
  Tree conflicts: 21 remaining (and 1 already resolved)
svn: E155027: Tree conflict can only be resolved to 'working' state; 'C:\Users\...\File.java' not resolved
```

How can I make it do theirs in all cases except use working for tree conflicts,

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in SVN using [--accept ACTION](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.accept) option:

```
svn merge --accept theirs-conflict
```

> --accept ACTION
>
> Specifies an action for automatic conflict resolution, disabling the interactive prompts which ask the user how to handle each conflict
>   as it is noticed. Though which of the specific actions are applicable
>   differs depending on which subcommand is in use, Subversion supports
>   the following long (and short) values for ACTION:
>
> ...
>
> theirs-conflict (tc)
>
> Resolve conflicted files by preferring the changes fetched from the server over local modifications in conflicting regions of each
>   file's content.

Comment: When I try to do the merge using --accept theirs-full I get an error.
It looks like It isn't handling tree conflicts. See Updated Section for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
svn merge --accept=theirs-full
```

And then:

```
svn resolve --accept=working C:\path\to\conflict
```

Comment: This requires manually creating a command for every conflict. I'm looking for a single command that will resolve all tree conflicts. Additionally, the `--accept=theirs-full` parameter, didn't resolve the regular conflicts.

Comment: The documentation states:
theirs-conflict
Discard any local changes which conflict with incoming changes from the server for the file under review. However, preserve all non-conflicting local changes to that file.
theirs-full
Discard all your local changes to the file under review and use only the newly received changes from the server for that file.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

Comment: So this should resolve any conflicts automatically.  You can write a simple script that runs the command on each file that needs to be resolved.